# Structural Pseudo Classes and attribute selectors doesn't work together

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have this HTML code :

```
<div class="field">                  
<input type="hidden" value="" name="a" id="a"> <input type="hidden" value="xxxx" name="b" id="b">
<input type="file" value="" name="file1"> <input type="file" value="" name="file2">
<input type="file" value="" name="file3"> <input type="file" value="" name="file4">
<input type="file" value="" name="file5"> <input type="file" value="" name="file6">
<input type="file" value="" name="file7"> <input type="file" value="" name="file8">     </div>
```

In this HTML, i want hide all input type="file" inside div class="field"except the first one.
I cannot change the HTML (adding classes).
I tried to apply a pseudoclasses and structurate selector toghether, to accomplish the task :

```
.field input[type='file']{
  display:none;
}

.field input[type='file']::first-child{
display:block;
}
```

But it seems doesn't work.
Anyone could suggest me the right syntax for using pseudo classes and selector togheter in css, to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo-classes use only one colon, so it's `:first-child`, not `::first-child`.

But your first `input[type='file']` is not the first child, so you can't use `:first-child` with it anyway.

You have to switch the rules around and use a sibling selector instead to hide the subsequent file upload inputs:

```
.field input[type='file'] {
    display:block;
}

.field input[type='file'] ~ input[type='file'] {
    display:none;
}
```

This technique is further described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107), and can be used for most other simple selectors, not just classes and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for all values and you will hide all input type="file" inside div class="field"except the first one. try this code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.field input[type='file']
{visibility:hidden;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```