# :first-of-type selector for input type="text"

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got the following situation:

```
<input type="hidden">
<input type="text">
<input type="hidden">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="hidden">
<input type="submit">
```

How can I select only the first two `input` that are `[type="text"]`?

As you can see here, the first `input[type="text"]` isn't styling as I need.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/99EZ6/3/)

Comment: Add a class to only the ones you want styled?

Comment: That's not possible using pure css if your number of input changes. Use javascript instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what their names might suggest, `:first-of-type` and `:nth-of-type()` do not consider the `type` attribute on `input` elements, or any other attribute on any other element. It only considers the type of element, which in the case of all your elements is `input`. By extension, `:first-child` and `:nth-child()` consider *all* children of the same parent when counting. Therefore, neither family of pseudo-classes can be used to solve your problem.

The fact that you're working with `input` elements makes this more difficult, due to the nature of form elements having special system default styles that cannot be applied using conventional CSS (or any CSS at all). Whether your problem can be solved depends on what sort of styles you wish to apply to the first two `input[type="text"]` elements.

If you're applying styles that won't adversely affect the default styles (such as `display: none`), or you don't care about the default styles at all, then using the [general sibling combinator `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) like I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452231/structural-pseudo-classes-and-attribute-selectors-doesnt-work-together/13452282#13452282) will work (note the use of two `~` combinators, since you're looking to style the first two elements and not just the first one):

```
input[type="text"] {
    /* 
     * Apply styles to all input[type="text"].
     */
}

input[type="text"] ~ input[type="text"] ~ input[type="text"] {
    /* 
     * Undo or override styles applied in the first rule for any input[type="text"]
     * that follows at least two other input[type="text"].
     */
}
```

Otherwise, if you need to preserve the default styles for subsequent elements, then this technique will not work as you cannot revert the default styles after modifying them. There does not appear to be a solution in that case.

Comment: My suggestion would be to add `.first` class or similar to objects you need to target